# How to manually add getters/mutations to a Vuex store, after it's already created?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to add new variables, getters and mutations in the 'created' lifecycle hook in one of my Vuejs components. The variables work fine. But with getters/mutations, it seems it's not as easy as adding new functions to the vuex store object. The problem I'm trying to solve is creating "shared" reusable components.

Here's the component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 class="headline">Number of items:</h2>
    <v-select
      :items="limits"
      item-value="value"
      item-text="text"
      label="Select"
      v-model="selected_limit"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {selectLimitComponentVariables} from './index';
  import {selectLimitComponentGetters} from './getters';
  import {selectLimitComponentMutations} from './mutations';

  export default {
    created: function () {
      // Add the variables
      Object.assign(this.$store.state[this.ns], selectLimitComponentVariables(this.var_prefix));
      // Add the getters
      Object.assign(this.$store.getters, selectLimitComponentGetters(this.ns, this.var_prefix));
      // Add the mutations
      Object.assign(this.$store._mutations, selectLimitComponentMutations(this.ns, this.var_prefix));
    },
    name: 'SelectLimitComponent',
    props: {
      ns: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      },
      var_prefix: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    },
    computed: {
      selected_limit: {
        get () {
          return this.$store.state[this.ns].selected_limit;
        },
        set (value) {
          this.$store.commit(`${this.ns}/update${this.var_prefix}selected_limit`, value)
        }
      },
      limits: {
        get() {
          return this.$store.state[this.ns].limits;
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And here are the imported functions.
selectLimitComponentVariables:

```
export const selectLimitComponentVariables = function (prefix) {
  return {
    [`${prefix}selected_limit`]: '100',
    [`${prefix}limits`]: [
      {'text': '10', 'value': '10'},
      {'text': '50', 'value': '50'},
      {'text': '100', 'value': '100'},
      {'text': '250', 'value': '250'},
      {'text': 'No limit', 'value': '-1'}]}
};
```

selectLimitComponentGetters:

```
export const selectLimitComponentGetters = function(namespace, prefix){
  return {
    [`${namespace}/${prefix}selected_limit`]: state => state[`${prefix}selected_limit`]
  }
};
```

selectLimitComponentMutations:

```
export const selectLimitComponentMutations = function (namespace, prefix){
  return {
    [`${namespace}/update${prefix}selected_limit`]: (state, newLimit) => state[`${prefix}selected_limit`] = newLimit
  }
};
```

Is there a way to manually add or register new getters/mutations, after the vuex store is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is have per-component Vuex state.

If you modify the Vuex schema at random like that, it would make it very difficult to manage the separation of state (you're just monkey-patching the root Vuex state).

Here's another approach. You could create a separate Vuex module and register it dynamically in the `beforeCreate` hook of your component.

```js
Vue.use(Vuex);

const HomeModule = {
  namespaced: true,
  state() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    },
  },
};

const ns = 'home';

Vue.component('home', {
  template: '<div><button @click="increment">+</button> {{ count }}</div>',
  beforeCreate() {
    if (!this.$store.state[ns]) {
      this.$store.registerModule(ns, HomeModule);
    }
  },
  computed: Vuex.mapState(ns, ['count']),
  methods: Vuex.mapMutations(ns, ['increment']),
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: new Vuex.Store(),  // Empty root store
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.3/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <home></home>
</div>
```

- I've used a `ns` global variable here, but you could obtain it from a prop like in your example.
- You can dynamically build the module instead of having it hardcoded.
- You can unregister the module as well upon component destruction if necessary.

Comment: It is better to do it in beforeCreate() than created(). Computed properties might be touched before created().

Comment: something similar can be also achieved with `<keep-alive/>`

Answer (score 8):

It's better to use `store.registerModule` feature of vuex to dynamically add new modules to vuex

```
this.$store.registerModule(`${this.ns}selected_limit`, {
  state: selectLimitComponentVariables...,
  getters: selectLimitComponentGetters...,
  mutations: selectLimitComponentMutations...,
  namespaced: true
})
```

You can check official document in `Dynamic Module Registration` section of https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem with adding values after instantiation is that they don't become reactive without using `set`

> When you are adding a new property that wasn’t present when the data
>   was observed. Due to the limitation of ES5 and to ensure consistent
>   behavior across browsers, Vue.js cannot detect property
>   addition/deletions. The best practice is to always declare properties
>   that need to be reactive upfront. In cases where you absolutely need
>   to add or delete properties at runtime, use the global Vue.set or
>   Vue.delete methods.

try this instead

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const selectLimitComponentMutations = function (namespace, prefix){
  return {
    [`${namespace}/update${prefix}selected_limit`]: (state, newLimit) => {
      Vue.$set(state, `${prefix}selected_limit`, newLimit);
    }
  }
};
```