# How to further extend state of an extended Javascript Class Module

Tags: javascript, vuex, extends

I am in the process of lessening the bulk of a Vuex store module that has grown too big and overly complex. Our state management system is built with Vuex using JS classes where we have a base module that is extended to multiple other more specific modules.
I am currently refactoring one of those more ‘specific’ modules - this module handles the state of a couple views containing a handful of components. I am attempting to extend this module the same as all of our other modules and use spread syntax to bring in the existing state properties…

```
export default class ChildModule extends BaseModule {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
       ...this.state
    }

    this.getters = {
       ...this.getters
    }
  }

    // ** the same syntax for actions and mutations 
    
    // logging rootState in an action inside GrandchildModule correct values from ChildModule
}
```

the only difference in the working module vs the broken module is the class that’s being extended…

```
export default class GrandchildModule extends ChildModule {...
```

for some reason that I haven’t figured out yet the `GrandchildModule` is not inheriting the state from the `ChildModule` properties that require fetching data from the api - properties that do not require api access are behaving correctly - I have been unsuccessful using getters in the `GrandchildModule` which I expected to be reactive to fetched data?

I’m hoping someone has some insight on how I can make this work or tell me what i’m doing wrong

update: found [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) on reactivity that i'm currently investigating - not 100% that this is my issue but it could be?

<strike>[example structure - stackblitz with js classes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tusds3?file=index.js)</strike>

### [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-starter-nfbbtk?file=README.md)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem with the stackblitz you shared is that in each of the classes (except `BaseClass`) you spread `state` in `constructor`. And `state` is not defined. You probably meant `this.state`:

```js
export default class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      ...this.state,
      name: 'ChildClass',
    };
  }
}
```

Secondly, in `index.js` you're attempting to display `GreatGrandchild.id` which, again, doesn't exist. `GreatGrandchild` is a JavaScript class declaration (which, technically, is a function with a single property: the `name` - the actual name of the class), so it doesn't have an `id`. Not even its instances (in your case, `timmy`) do not have an `id`. But they do have a `state.id`.

For a better understanding of how JavaScript classes work, I recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

If you want to reference the inherited `state.id` (from `BaseClass > ChildClass > GrandchildClass > GreatGrandchild`), you could use:

```
const timmy = new GreatGrandchild();
console.log(timmy.state.id); // output: 0
```

See it working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uhkywx?file=index.js).

---

From the example you posted it's unclear how your code is related to `vuex`. Or `vue`, for that matter. You might want to provide a minimal runnable example with what you have.

However, on general principles, I would not recommend extending Vuex stores. Once a store has been instantiated, new members added to its `state`, `actions`, `mutations` or `getters` will not be reactive. If you're determined to take that route, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331314/how-to-manually-add-getters-mutations-to-a-vuex-store-after-its-already-create) might help.

What could work for your case is a `BaseClass` which doesn't actually create a store, but holds the common store props and then have different store classes which actually create stores after merging the base class's props with their own. Something along these lines:

```
class BaseStore {
  constructor() {
    // place here what you want defined on all stores
    this.state = {
      // ...
    };
    this.actions = {
      // ...
    };
    this.getters = {
      // ...
    };
    this.mutations = {
      // ...
    };
  }
}

class SomeStore extends BaseStore {
  constructor({ state = {}, mutations = {}, actions = {}, getters = {} }) {
    super();
    return new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        ...this.state,
        ...state,
      },
      actions: {
        ...this.actions,
        ...actions,
      },
      getters: {
        ...this.getters,
        ...getters,
      },
      mutations: {
        ...this.mutations,
        ...mutations,
      },
    });
  }
}

class SomeOtherStore extends BaseStore {
  constructor({ state = {}, mutations = {}, actions = {}, getters = {} }) {
    super();
    return new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        ...this.state,
        ...state,
      },
      actions: {
        ...this.actions,
        ...actions,
      },
      getters: {
        ...this.getters,
        ...getters,
      },
      mutations: {
        ...this.mutations,
        ...mutations,
      },
    });
  }
}

// declare or import state, actions, getters, mutations, otherState, otherActions, otherMutations and otherGetters

const myFirstStore = new SomeStore({
  state,
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations
});

const myOtherStore = new SomeOtherStore({
  state: otherState,
  actions: otherActions,
  mutations: otherMutations,
  getters: otherGetters
})
```

Although the above pattern is possible, I'm skeptical about its usefulness in a real world scenario. I'm far from recommending it. The main reason is because classes are useful when you want to handle multiple instances of the same class. It's difficult to imagine a scenario where having multiple instances of the same store would be useful.

---

**Note**: I've used Vuex 3 instantiation method, because I guessed you're using Vue2 + Vuex 3. If you use Vue 3 + Vuex 4, you should replace `new Vuex.Store()` with `createStore()`

---

**Another note**: the above example could be written without using classes. I'd argue it's a bit cleaner:

```js
const defaultStoreProps = {
  state: {
    // common state
  },
  actions: {
    // common actions
  },
  // etc...
}

const myFirstStore = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
     ...defaultStoreProps.state,
     // other state
   },
   actions: {
     ...defaultStoreProps.actions,
     // other actions
   },
   // etc...
})

const mySecondStore = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    ...defaultStoreProps.state,
    // other state
  },
  actions: {
    ...defaultStoreProps.actions,
    // other actions
  },
  // etc...
})
```

Comment: thank you, you've given me a lot to chew on - I'm especially interested in the class-less, very much cleaner option you included - thank you again for taking the time, very much appreciated - also the link you added mentioning a per-component store was spot on

Comment: If you need 1 store per component, you don't need that store. That's because the component is already a store: the `data` would be the `state`, `computed` would be the `getters` and you can use `methods` as `actions` and `mutations`. The pattern is there. You want stand-alone stores when you consume them by at least two separate components.

Comment: i added an updated stackblitz that includes our general structure including Vue and Vuex along with some generic class modules - im curious if your 'skeptical about its usefulness' opinion holds true - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-starter-nfbbtk?file=src/store/modules/base.js

Comment: the end goal is lessening the bulk of a store module by extending and collecting like properties - the updated stackblitz is a generic'ed version of our implementation - the stores are instantiated once, as vuex stores - this should keep things reactive right? If not, why?  Is my only option using $set?

Comment: @MCGRAW, the link you shared is a 404.

Comment: dang - sorry about that. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-starter-nfbbtk?file=src/App.vue @tao

Comment: @MCGRAW, I've already tried accessing the root of https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-starter-nfbbtk and it returns 404. Make sure you don't need to be logged it to view it. It might have some "Share" button which gives you a share-able link to it. Try accessing what you shared in an incognito window to see what everyone else is seeing.

Comment: i switched from 'url accessible' to 'public' https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-starter-nfbbtk?file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue
i also have a public github repo https://github.com/mmcgraw73/store-refactor-vue2-vuex3 @tao

Comment: You seem to have it working (for the most part, except you shouldn't count on a `computed` to trigger a call to an API. Instead, you should use [mounted()](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-starter-1zxlug?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue%3AL15). But I don't see a reason why you should use inheritance. As far as I can see, you could as well have three separate base stores and get the same functionality.